# If Lubuntu uses the same repositories as Ubuntu, can it have OpenShot & GIMP?

Tags: lubuntu, software-sources, gimp, openshot

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm considering switching to Lubuntu since my machine is pretty old for this heavy OS. I read it uses the same repositories as Ubuntu, but when trying Lubuntu from a disk on key the "shop" (app market) did not show GIMP or OpenShot in search.

I noticed Lubuntu has a built in tool similar to GIMP but I would like to use those two I mentioned.

So will I have a problem if I switch?

Comment: yes, lubuntu uses the sam repositories, Lubunut is Ubuntu but with a light weight desktop. All of the same programs will be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read [Lubuntu] uses the same repositories as Ubuntu

You read right. The difference between Ubuntu and Lubuntu is the desktop environment, which is a collection of packages. All flavors of Ubuntu use the same software repositories, and therefore have the same packages available to install, although they have different applications installed by default, particularly GUI software that makes up the DE.

> When trying Lubuntu from a disk [...] the "shop" (app market) did not show GIMP or OpenShot in search

I think this is because those two packages are in the Universe repository, which was not available in the live environment. The Universe repository should be available after installation, but if it isn't, you can easily enable it:

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

After that, GIMP and OpenShot should appear when you search in the AppMarket. If for some reason they don't, you can install them using APT:

```
sudo apt install gimp openshot
```

Comment: "Lubuntu is a Ubuntu flavour which uses `LXDE` as default desktop environment" This would be correct, right ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ran hmm yes that makes more sense than what I wrote. I should edit my answer to be more accurate, thanks!